# Vertical full screen paging using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm attempting to create a vertically paging `UICollectionView` using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, similar to how TikTok scrolls its feed. I'm very close to achieving that experience, however, the cells aren't being sized the way I expect them to, which is to be full screen width and height. Here is the layout I came up with that scrolls vertically while paging:

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
)
let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
)
let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    layoutSize: groupSize,
    subitems: [layoutItem]
)

let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging

let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
config.scrollDirection = .horizontal

let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: layoutSection, configuration: config)
return layout
```

And here is a screenshot of the cells in the collectionview (I'm using random colors for each cell):

[image]

Interestingly, if I set `config.scrollDirection = .vertical`, the cells are sized the way I expect (full screen size) but it scrolls horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
config.contentInsetsReference = .none
```

Comment: Excellent. This did the trick. This property only works for iOS 14.0+. My project was targeting 13.0. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Would you happen to know if there is a way to get the results I'm looking for without using the `contentInsetsReference` property? I am hoping it's possible since I am unable to change my deploy target from 13.0.